# SceneKit server-client non-rendering scene

Tags: swift, client-server, game-engine, scenekit

I'm working on a server-client based networked game in Scene Kit. Since the server and the client essentially have duplicate copies of the game, I'm currently loading the same scenes into an SCNScene on the client side and SCNScene on the server. However, I have yet to find a way to actually run the physics simulation on the server's copy of the SCNScene without rendering it in an SCNView. How can I set up a (custom SCNRenderer?) that drives the simulation without actually rasterizing any frames?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the SCNRenderer, overrides all methods {void}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).